# What is the name of huge ads along motorways

Tags: word-request

Is there any special name for ads which are placed along highways and especially  I would like to ask for McDonald's as in the picture..

For example I would like to make a sentence like :

> After you get on the highway, keep on driving .After about 30 minutes
> you will see a huge McDonald's.........

[image]

Comment: Large flat signs are *billboards*,  and the advertising on the canopy in front of a theater is a *marquee*, but I don't know a concise synonym for advertising signs. Perhaps someone can answer this, or perhaps English needs a new word for these monstrosities. [Copycat large homes are called *McMansions*, so these could be *McAdvertisement*?]

Comment: As far as I know, they're just generically "Signs".  There's no special term used by the masses.  It's possible that there's a term for them within the industry but I don't think it's widely known.

Comment: Is it a sign like the one in your image or is it a billboard like this one: http://www.inrixtraffic.com/wp-content/uploads/mcdonalds-billboard.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example you show is a *sign*. specifically, it is an *advertising sign* (as distinguished from, for instance, a traffic information sign).

The "M" (double arches) on the sign is a *logo*. In the case of McDonalds, the logo is so universally recognized that the sign would be effective in drawing customers even if the sign did not include the McDonalds name.

It is **not** a *billboard*. As commenter pointed out, a *billboard* is a large flat panel (board); it is usually on supports to lift it high in the air for visibility. http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=webhp&tbm=isch&source=hp&ei=YMw9VbCtM8vWoAThhoDIBA&q=billboard&oq=billboard

Answer (score 3):

We hear many words for these huge ads such as large advertising signs, largebsignboard, or just large signs.  In advertising industry, we call it a billboard both in AE and BE.

You can also call it a hoarding in BE.

Some advertising signs are also called neon signs, which shine at night because of neon (gas) when electric current is passed through it.

According to The Free Dictionary, a billboard/hoarding means a large signboard. The highway was lined with large signboards.

As for McDonald's, you cannot call it a billboard or a hoarding; it's McDonald's sign. According to The Free Dictionary, "sign" is a structure used for posting advertisements or for identifying a place of business.

Comment: I've never heard anyone call something a billboard that wasn't a large flat sign, usually rented from a third party and changed to have different content from time to time.  Also, most "neon signs" aren't actually made with neon any more... more are made with argon.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: I think a sign made from glowing glass tubes is generally called a "neon sign" regardless of what chemical is actually used in it. Just like I still say "my phone is ringing" even though modern phones rarely "ring", but rather play some little piece of electronically-generated music. Etc.

Comment: @Jay I said what I did because his answer is ambiguous at best and I thought it was worth clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Unipole or monopole advertising signs = advertising signs (various formats) standing on a single pole. Volumetric signage could be mounted (see McPhoto above) billboards (like 48' x 14' bulletin boards).

Ressources:

[Wikipedia - about unipole signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unipole_sign)

[Wizard Media - about unipole signs](http://www.wizard-media.ro/panouri-2013/en-unipole-signs/14x4-bulletin-board/)

Answer (score 0):

It's either a hoarding or a billboard

> **[hoarding](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hoarding?q=hoarding)**- (British English) (also billboard North American English, British English) [countable]: **a large board on the outside of a building or at the side of the road,** used for putting advertisements on*

It typically talks what you are concerned about-roadside/outside the building.

The answer ends here!

---

If we see through a *microscopic eye*, hoardings are the *advertisements* found on *other buildings/road sides*. However, what you are talking is the building of **McDonald's itself**. I'd call it as a 'board' because it's not an advertisement, it's the company's building itself. They just need to ***show*** that it's McD's building, not to **promote**. You may say that **without** mentioning billboard/sign/hoarding etc.!

> After you get on the highway, keep on driving. After about 30 minutes you will see McDonald's.

If you still want to emphasize on the Big M or McDonald's words,

> After you get on the highway, keep on driving. After about 30 minutes you will see McDonald's with a *huge board*.

I thought of *signboard* first, but it won't be correct.

---

**Interesting**

Soon, we'll notice a new oxymoron word: 'tiny hoardings'! **or** lexicographers will have to come up with a new word that describes a small billboard. **[Marvel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Comics)** will force them to do so with their movie Antman.

### [Tiny Billboards for Ant-Man Are Popping Up That Ants Are Really Going to Love](http://www.adweek.com/adfreak/tiny-billboards-ant-man-are-popping-ants-are-really-going-love-164221)

---

[image]